# Adding new enumerators to an Enum specifier using CDT ASTRewrite

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a header file with an Enum with a set of enumerators, e.g.,

```
typedef enum MyEnum{
  A = 0,
  B = 1
}
```

I want to add a new enumerator like `C = 2` to the end of it.

So I tried to do it using the `ASTRewrite` like below:

```
public void addEnumerator(IASTTranslationUnit ast, String enumName, String name, String value){
  INodeFactory nodeFactory = ast.getASTNodeFactory();
  ASTRewrite astRewrite =  ASTRewrite.create(ast);
  ast.accept(new ASTVisitor(true) {
     @Override
     public int visit(IASTDeclSpecifier declSpec) {
       if (declSpec instanceof IASTEnumerationSpecifier 
&& ((IASTEnumerationSpecifier) declSpec).getName().getRawSignature().equals(enumName)) {
         IASTName nameNode = nodeFactory.newName(name);
         IASTExpression valueNode = nodeFactory.newLiteralExpression  
             (IASTLiteralExpression.lk_integer_constant, value);
         IASTEnumerator newEnumerator = nodeFactory.newEnumerator(nameNode, valueNode);
         astRewrite.insertBefore(declSpec, null, newEnumerator, null);
             return ASTVisitor.PROCESS_SKIP;
         }
      return super.visit(declSpec);
    }
  });
  Change change = rewrite.rewriteAST();
  try {
      change.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());
  } catch (CoreException exp) {
       LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(exp));
  }
}
```

However, the change object does not reflect the changes!

Based on my checks on CDT src code, apprently, [only `IASTDeclaration` and `IASTStatement` are allowed for APPEND_CHILD modification operation](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cdt-nsight/blob/master/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/parser/org/eclipse/cdt/internal/core/dom/rewrite/changegenerator/ChangeGenerator.java#L296) but I don't understand why and how I can do the modification that I need (which is of type `IASTEnumerator`)!

Comment: You might get more attention asking in the [eclipse cdt discussions](https://github.com/eclipse-cdt/cdt/discussions) on github